# verb. "to shoot" (weapon): difference between 射击，开枪， 击中， 射中

Tags: difference, verbs

The verb *shoot* appears often in Chinese international news. But I am unclear about the different words for it.

射击 and 开枪 seem to be the firing of a gun and 击中，射中 hitting with a weapon, but could someone clarify the difference?

My dictionary says "hit with missile". Can any of these words be used for a rocket / missile attack too or are they only applicable to handguns and sporting guns?

I also wonder why the word 中 is part of these words in the context of shooting.

Thank you very much.

Comment: 枪 specifically refers to some sort of "gun", so phrases with it would be inappropriate for, say, missiles and rockets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- `射击` is "shooting".
- `开枪` is "to pull the trigger (on a gun)".

So a shooting sport would be called `射击運動`, and cover fire is called `掩護射击`.

- `击中` means "hitting".
- `射中` means "hitting with a flying object".

It works with a self-propelled missile/artillery shell/arrows etc too.

The `中` is there to to contribute the meaning of a "hit" to the terms. `射` without `中` is only "shooting"; with `中` it becomes "shooting *and hitting*"

Comment: thank you so much, that helps a lot, especially the first 2 words. About the last two if you don't mind, would 射中 then be used more for arrows and long range missiles and 击中 seems to be more the direct hit of a bomb or handgun?

Comment: Not really; 射中 basically works with anything you shoot. 擊中 doesn't have to be about missile objects; it just means a hit. You can use it for a fist, for instance.

Comment: I see, I notice it being used for soccer shots too now, ty

Comment: 中(zhong4) in 击中 and 射中 is the key meaning, hitting or goal, of the words. 击 and 射 just emphasize how to archive the target.

Comment: @user2550062 That's basically what I said already, except 击 and 射  does not "emphasize" in any meaningful sense of the word. They provide additional info.

Comment: 开枪 is more like "fire".